# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2/9/2016 10:30:00 AM (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada)"

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, timezone

I am getting exception when trying to parse this date :

"2/9/2016 10:30:00 AM (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)" code

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d/m/yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa zzz", Locale.ENGLISH); 
format.parse("2/9/2016 10:30:00 AM (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada)");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used `m` for the month which is wrong. You have to use `M` for the month and `m` for the minute.

I also recommend you use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale)) instead of using the outdated `SimpleDateFormat`. Check [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) to learn more about the modern date/time API.

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .appendPattern("d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss a (zzz)")
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2/9/2016 10:30:00 AM (GMT-05:00)", formatter);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2016-09-02T10:30-05:00[GMT-05:00]
```

**Also,**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .appendPattern("d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss a (zzz)")
                .appendLiteral(" Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2/9/2016 10:30:00 AM (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
                formatter);
        System.out.println(zdt);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(zdt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2016-09-02T10:30-05:00[GMT-05:00]
2/9/2016 10:30:00 AM (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
```

Answer (score 1):

The date you are parsing does not match with the format,

m is for a minute, M for Month, This will works,

```
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa (zzz)", Locale.ENGLISH);

    format.parse("2/9/2016 10:30:00 AM (GMT)");
```

You can use [Java SimpleDateFormat Online Tester](http://www.sdfonlinetester.info/#) to create format for date:2/9/2016 10:30:00 AM **(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada).**

Hope this help you,

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

Like others I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/u h:mm:ss a (OOOO)", Locale.ENGLISH);

    String stringToParse = "2/9/2016 10:30:00 AM (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)";

    ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
    TemporalAccessor parsed = formatter.parse(stringToParse, pp);
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.from(parsed);

    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output is:

> 2016-09-02T10:30-05:00

`Eastern Time (US & Canada)` is not considered a time zone in the time zone database that Java uses, so we cannot parse this part of the string using `DateTimeFormatter` or `SimpleDateFormat`. To parse only a portion of the string I am using the `DateTimeFormatter.parse` method that accepts a `ParsePosition`. If we wanted, we might use the `ParsePosition` afterwards for determining how much of the string had been parsed.

### What went wrong in your code?

- The reason for your `ParseException` is that `(GMT-05:00)` doesn’t match `zzz` in the format pattern string. Or more precisely, your format pattern doesn’t include the round bracket that is in the string to be parsed.
- As others have said, you need uppercase `M` for month in the format pattern. Lowercase `m` is for minute. This would cause an incorrect result. While `SimpleDateFormat` ought to throw an exception on the grounds of this error alone, it does not.
- You finally need lower case `h` or `hh` for hour within AM or PM from 01 through 12. Upper case `HH` is for hour of day from 00 through 23.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.